# Automate token distribution?

Tags: contract-design, tokens, erc-20, php

How can I execute a function on a smart contract from a web-app backend? (Laravel / PHP)

My smart contracts holds X tokens.

In my MySQL database, users are owed X tokens. I have their wallet addresses.

How can I securely send X tokens to N addresses, and automate it so its not a manual process?

```
Eg -> run cron job every night
   -> smart contract gets list of addresses & values
   .... how can I do this securely?
```

Answer (score 0):

This design is inherently centralized and periodic distributions will not change that.

Since the accounting is already in a mysql database it will not be a setback to continue that way. Present a function to request withdrawal on demand, and have the server send users their tokens when they ask for them.

On the other hand, if a decentralized design is the aim then the changes will be much deeper, before it gets to this point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks great rob thanks! Will update with some code when I get around to it. In the future hopefully the app will become a dapp.